# How to Draw checkbox in WPF using DrawingContext c#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, drawingcontext

Hi i need to draw an checkbox within the rectangle.is there any predefined method in c# WPF .or how to i acheive this senario in WPF.

Answer (score 4):

You may try this:

```
 CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
 checkbox.Content = "Content";
 checkbox.Height = 50;
 checkbox.Width = 100;
 checkbox.IsChecked = true;
 checkbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

 VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(checkbox);
 drawingContext.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(50, 50, 100, 50));
```

Answer (score -1):

1.) Create the Rectanle

2.) Create the checkbox

3.) use rectangle.Controls.Add(checkbox)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. but rectangle means in this case i have a rectangle area. not the real rectangle element.

Comment: should still work all the same, check if there is a .Control on your rectangle area.

Comment: This is a low-effort answer IMO. Step 2 is basically stating the question.